# Trying to use "setVariable"

Tags: java, string

Trying to use `setVaraible()` to make the String `"Hometown"` equal user input, so it can be called back later. Someone else previously helped me with something of this nature, but it was used in a loop, so I can't exactly see how it worked.

```
private static String InputName; 
private static String Sex; 
private static String Age; 
private static String input; 
private static String Hometown;
```

It looked like this:

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
      input = sc.next();
      System.out.println("");
       setVariable(a, input);
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            sc.close();
            break;
        }
        else if(a>questions.length -1)
        {
            a = 0;
        }
        else{
            a++;
        }
        if(a>questions.length -1){
            System.out.println("Fine, " + InputName 
                    + ", so, you are " + Age + " years old and " + Sex + "." );
            System.out.println("");
            sleep();
             System.out.println("Do you need to change any information?\n"); 

          }
           if(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("no") && a<questions.length){
          System.out.println(questions[a]);
          }
```

And, I just need it here (I know this code is wrong):

```
static public void Intro() {
    int a = 0;

     setVariable(3, Hometown);
    String[] questions = {"What do you want to name your hometown?"};
    System.out.println(questions);
     input = sc.next();
}
```

Here is the `setVariable()` method:

```
static void setVariable(int a, String Field) { 
    switch (a) { 
        case 0: 
            InputName = Field;
            return;
        case 1:
            Age = Field;
            return;
        case 2:
            Sex = Field;
            return;
        case 3:
            Hometown = Field;
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Code can become a lot harder to read when `Age` and `Hometown` are named as if they are classes, when they are only Strings.

Comment: Where is your `setVariable()` method?

Comment: Why not just `String a = input;`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this site, so, thanks for the editing feedback.

Comment: I've tried everything I know, and I do not understand the syntax of how to do this.

@Elliot Frisch: I do not know in what context to use that.

Comment: Do you understand **your** code?

Comment: Why do you have this `setVariable` method? It violates several Java conventions, including naming (capitalization) of variables, using individual setters for different fields, and using type-safe enums instead of `int`s for this sort of selector.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can call `setVariable` by passing it two values, the first is a `int` value which represents field to be set and the second is the value to apply, for example

```
setVariable(0, "This is the input name");
```

Would set the `InputName` variable to "This is the input name"

Using `1` would allow you to change the `Age` variable, `2` the `Sex` variable and `3` the `Hometown` variable, so basically, what you need to try is something like...

```
setVariable(3, "New home town value");
```

For example...

Currently your code looks something like...

```
static public void Intro() {
    int a = 0;

    setVariable(3, Hometown);
    String[] questions = {"What do you want to name your hometown?"};
    System.out.println(questions);
    input = sc.next();
}
```

Which basically assigns the current value of `Hometown` to itself...which is probably `null`, then you try and read a value from the `Scanner`

Try it the other way round, for example...

```
static public void Intro() {
    System.out.println("What do you want to name your hometown?");
    input = sc.nextLine();
    setVariable(3, input);
}
```

Making sure you pass the `input` value to the method, so it can assign the value to the correct field...

Personally, I don't find this either useful or intuitive.  Sure you could use an `enum` or even define `static final` variables that would make determine which field you want to change easier, but Java is an Object Oriented language, we might as well make use of it...

I would encourage you to define a `Person` object (for argument sake) with which you can set/get the individual properties of the object, for example...

```
public class Person {
    private String inputName; 
    private String sex; 
    private String age; 
    private String hometown;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.inputName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return inputName;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setHometown(String hometown) {
        this.hometown = hometown;
    }

    public String getHometown() {
        return hometown;
    }
}
```

Then you would simply create a new instance of `Person`

```
Person person = new Person();
```

And fill it out...

```
person.setName("Ruphet");
person.setSex("Male");
person.setAge("18");
person.setHometown("Murembugie");
```

And when you need to show or "get" some value...

```
System.out.println("Hello " + person.getName() + " from " + person.getHometown());
```

ps-

You might like to take a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), it will make it easier for others to read your code (and for you to read others)...

Comment: Though why not to use individual getters and setters is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm getting to it ;)

Comment: I get it, but I'm still getting errors. Tried using `setVariable(3, input)`, and `input = sc.next();`, but the program just terminates and doesn't ask the question.

Comment: @Jarvis You also need to supply a runnable example as it may highlight other problem areas...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I think I've gotten it. The error that I was receiving seems to be from another class that I deleted and it's.. persisting or something. It keeps telling me that there's an error with my Game class, and I no longer have that class. Thanks! This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
// This method should not be static, but your Hometown is.
public static void setHometown(String input) {
  // This should not be a static variable, also it shouldn't be capitalized.
  if (input == null) {
    Hometown = "";
  } else {
    Hometown = input;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you're filling out `person.setName();`, couldn't the parameters be set to user input? So... and if I'm doing this right: `person.setName(input);` and `input = sc.next();`.

Comment: Correct. `setName(String)` would take a `String input`.